# Google people API returning empty / no results in Python

Tags: api, google-api, google-people-api

I'm trying to read contacts from my person gmail account and the instructions provided by Google from the People API is returning an empty list. I'm not sure why. I've tried another [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38680216/people-connections-list-not-returning-contacts-using-python-client-library) from a few years ago, but that doens't seem to work. I've pasted my code below. Any help troubleshooting this is appreciated!

```
import os.path
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.json.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly']

from google.oauth2 import service_account

SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = '<path name hidden>.json'

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
        SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)

def main():
    #Shows basic usage of the People API.
    #Prints the name of the first 10 connections.
    
    creds = None
    

    service = build('people', 'v1', credentials=credentials)

    # Call the People API
    print('List 10 connection names')
    results = service.people().connections().list(
        resourceName='people/me',
        pageSize=10,
        personFields='names,emailAddresses').execute()
    connections = results.get('connections', [])

    request = service.people().searchContacts(pageSize=10, query="A", readMask="names")

    results = service.people().connections().list(resourceName='people/me',personFields='names,emailAddresses',fields='connections,totalItems,nextSyncToken').execute() 


    for i in results:
        print ('result', i)

    for person in connections:
        names = person.get('names', [])
        if names:
            name = names[0].get('displayName')
            print(name)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Have you tried the [quickstart](https://developers.google.com/people/quickstart/python) if it works on you?

Comment: I think that the reason of your issue might be due to the use of the service account. Because the service account is different from your personal account. So for example, how about using OAuth2 instead of the service account?